# Javascript to read/write files on the client side

Tags: javascript, file

i need make a javascript code that reads a file from the client computer, specified by the user, something like an upload form but to be only processed by javascript, no server needed. And after processing the data, i need to give the user a file to download containing the processed data.
is there a way to do so? i think it's something about html5, not sure.
i'm new to javascript.

Comment: Check File API: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Comment: You could start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications. Then if you have problems implementing it, come back with the code and any errors, a live demo and we'll try to help.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: thank you guys, now i can read files, what about the second part? making the user download a file containing data processed within the js code?